# how to indent if statements like the following?

Tags: eclipse, settings, formatter

Problem:

```
private int method1() {
    if(some statement) return something;
    else if (some statement) return something;
    else retrun something;
```

I Want the following indentation by changing the eclipse settings

```
private int method1() {
    if      (some statement) return something;
    else if (some statement) return something;
    else                     retrun something;
```

Anyone know which settings to change in eclipse to have the above indentation?

Comment: Only [field and variable declarations and assignment statements can be align in columns like that](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.9/jdt.php#align-spaces). You have to write your own formatter to align _if_-statements as well (Eclipse provides an extension point for that).

Comment: I see. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, ***if* statements cannot be aligned in columns**. Only [field and variable declarations and assignment statements can be aligned in columns](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.9/jdt.php#align-spaces) like that.

You have to write your own formatter to align if-statements as well ([Eclipse provides an extension point for that](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_jdt_core_javaFormatter.html)).